# Check File And Not Only Extension PHP

Tags: php, upload

I looked around for this but I could not find any specific information for my problem.

I'm using `jquery.validate` to check if the extension of an uploaded file is correct. I also tried it with Mime-type check from Jquery.

Both ways only check the extension. I can create a text file, rename the extension to pdf or word, and the file will pass. Of course the files are corrupted.

Is there a way true php that I can check the file itself and not only the extension? Here is what I got so far:

```
<?php

require_once '../lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $geslacht = $_POST['title'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required


        $d='C:/wamp/www//upload/';
        $de=$d . basename($_FILES['bestand']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["bestand"]["tmp_name"], $de)) {

    }else {

         echo "<script>alert('Bestand kon niet worden geupload')</script>";
    };
$fileName = $_FILES['bestand']['name'];
    $filePath = $_FILES['bestand']['tmp_name'];
     //add only if the file is an upload

  }
else
  {

  }


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Host = '';
$mail->Username ='';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;


$mail->From = ';
$mail->FromName = "$geslacht $first_name $last_name";
$mail->AddAddress('', '');
$mail->Subject = "Sollicitatie van $geslacht $first_name $last_name";
$mail->Body = "$geslacht $first_name $last_name heeft zijn/haar CV Gestuurd! Klik op bijlage om te bekijken. Het email adres van deze persoon is $email_from";
$mail->AddAttachment($de, $_FILES['bestand']['name']);
 var_dump($mail->Send());
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks guys!

Comment: There's a linux command to check what the file has. I'm not sure which one is it. You can use it **WITH EXTREME CAUTION** and parse the results

Comment: why with extrem caution ? You got more information about that command ?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/file Command `file`, use it like `file --mime <filename>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use finfo_file function, read more about it here:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php.

This function returns information about a file by its contents, regardless of the extension.

You can use it like that:

```
<?php
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    echo $finfo->file("<file_path>"); //outputs file type
?>
```

Hope that helps.